# [rviz-3] process has died. [epuck2_robot_0-1] process has died

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 via WSL, installed ROS Kinetic to work with my E-puck2 robot, I created a catkin_workspace and installed all dependencies, there was no error when I issued catkin_make command, issued roscore command on another terminal and it started roscore service. I sourced my files on another terminal using

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash  
chmod +x ./src/epuck_driver/scripts/epuck2_driver.py to mark the driver node as executable
roslaunch epuck_driver epuck2_controller.launch epuck2_address:='b4:e6:2d:ed:07:a7'
```

with MAC address according to my e-puck's, the roslaunch server started, listing a summary of parameters and nodes, but then the rviz process died and epuck's process died too. The E-puck's process keep restarting and dying.
Could anyone please help me out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345908/%5Brviz-3%5D-process-has-died.-%5Bepuck2_robot_0-1%5D-process-has-died./) by [yabdulra](https://answers.ros.org/users/52229/yabdulra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First: WSL is not a supported runtime environment for ROS. It comes with a special set of requirements and constraints that none of the ROS packages have been tested for. You can certainly try to use ROS in a WSL environment, but know that you'll most likely run into difficulties.

Having written that: if the driver requires access to hardware, it's likely it can't work in WSL, as WSL does not support direct access to hw. If it just needs a network connection, it *may* work.

As to RViz: WSL does not come with an X-server, so GUI applications will not work by default. You'll have to install an X-server on the Windows side. There are a few Q&As about this here on ROS Answers you may want to look up (use Google, and append `site:answers.ros.org` to your search query). But even with an X-server there is no guarantee running RViz (and/or Gazebo) will work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yabdulra](https://answers.ros.org/users/52229/yabdulra/) on 2020-03-05**:
Thank you for this comment. I'll install Ubuntu alongside widows and start all over.

**Comment by [yabdulra](https://answers.ros.org/users/52229/yabdulra/) on 2020-03-08**:
I'm using ROS on a VM installed ubuntu, and these problems are no more now. Thank you once again.